# Attach a single IAM policy to two separate roles in two different regions (same account) using terraform and apex

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I have a terraform infrastructure setup, where a module is being used in different environments (same account, different regions). The issue I have is that for each environment I need to attach the policy to a Role in that environment. So every time I try to update the infrastructure using `apex infra -e <env> apply`, the Role previously attached to the Policy is overwritten by the Role in the new environment.

`Terraform v0.12.13`

`Apex version 1.0.0-rc2`

Is there any way to tell terraform, **to add the Role to the current list of Roles attached to a policy?**

```
data "aws_iam_policy" "ecsPolicy" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "ecs_task_attach" {
  name       = "${var.apex_environment}_ecsTaskExec"
  roles      = [aws_iam_role.ecs_task_executor_role.name]
  policy_arn = data.aws_iam_policy.ecsPolicy.arn
}
```

Creating separate policies to attach to different users would be my last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aws_iam_policy_attachment` creates exclusive attachment of IAM Policies and override any existing policy attached to the IAM Role.

If you are looking to attach multiple policies to a Single IAM Role, then try using `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment` (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role_policy_attachment.html). This resource should help you to achieve your goal.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great to hear :)